# Change internal color of radioButton android

Tags: android, colors, radio-button

I would like to change the internal color of a `RadioButton` in android studio. I have tried the `android:buttonTint` method, but that changes the color of the outer circle on the radio button as well. Is there a way to only change the inside color of a `RadioButton`, while keeping a black outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your values/styles.xml:

Add this in your App theme:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        //Green is the color of the pressed state and activated state
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>   //add this
        //black is the color of the normal state
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>  //Add this
    </style>
```

Now use the theme in your Activity: in Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".Main_activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Comment: What do I put in my mainActivity of my xml?